# How can I modelize the following model in JPA/Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I modelize the following model in JPA/Hibernate mapping

---

### DDL for Table SME_ANCHOR

```
  CREATE TABLE "IRIS"."SME_ANCHOR" 
   (    "NAME" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), 
    "REPORT_PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "INDUSTRY_CODE" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), 
    "ACTIVE_FLAG" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "PORTFOLIO_PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "POSTAL_CODE" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR)
   ) 
ALTER TABLE "IRIS"."SME_ANCHOR" ADD CONSTRAINT "SAR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PKID", "ACTIVE_FLAG")
```

---

### DDL for Table LOAN_SME

```
  CREATE TABLE "IRIS"."LOAN_SME" 
   (    "SME_ANCHOR_PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "LOAN_ANCHOR_PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "ACTIVE_FLAG" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
   ) 
ALTER TABLE "IRIS"."LOAN_SME" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_LOAN_SME" PRIMARY KEY ("SME_ANCHOR_PKID", "ACTIVE_FLAG", "LOAN_ANCHOR_PKID")
```

---

### DDL for Table LOAN_ANCHOR

```
  CREATE TABLE "IRIS"."LOAN_ANCHOR" 
   (    "LOAN_ID_STRD" VARCHAR2(240 CHAR), 
    "PORTFOLIO_PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "REPORT_PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), 
    "CURRENCY" VARCHAR2(250 CHAR), 
    "PURPOSE" VARCHAR2(253 CHAR), 
    "PKID" VARCHAR2(32 CHAR), 
    "ACTIVE_FLAG" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
   )
ALTER TABLE "IRIS"."LOAN_ANCHOR" ADD CONSTRAINT "LAR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PKID", "ACTIVE_FLAG")
```

The difficulty here it's to modelize entities who have key composed of 2 elements and a foreign key composed of 3 elements.
How can I solved this.
I'm trying to do a @ManyToMany association but with not success.
Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Your table design does not specifies the relationship between them. Can you pls specify the relationship between them clearly?

Comment: You should try it yourself and then post the code with your questions, if there will be any.

Answer (score 1):

Try manytomany with relationship table. Some thing like this.. I did not try it with you case but it worked for me in a similar case.

```
   <many-to-many attribute-type="java.util.Set" fetch="EAGER" name="forwarderInstitutions" target-entity="com.temp.LoanAnchor">
        <join-table name="LOAN_SME">
          <inverse-join-column name="LOAN_ANCHOR_PKID" referenced-column-name="PKID"/>
          <join-column name="SME_ANCHOR_PKID" referenced-column-name="PKID"/>
          <join-column name="ACTIVE_FLAG" referenced-column-name="ACTIVE_FLAG"/>
        </join-table>
      </many-to-many>
```

---

Comment: thanks for your help but not working due to the composite key in loan_anchor and sme_anchor.
I got this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(PKID) of org.eif.disys.iris.model.SmeAnchor.loanAnchors referencing org.eif.disys.iris.model.LoanAnchor not mapped to a single property.